# Can't get Mongoose.js 3 level Subdocument Array to populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose.js on a node.js server connecting to mongodb and I have a mongoose model like the following:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    qtde: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0.0,
        required: 'Digite a quantidade'
    },
    detalhe: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Detalhe'
    },
    produto: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Produto'
    }
});


var DetalheSchema = new Schema({
    dia: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Digite o Dia do coffee'
    },
    orcamento: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Orcamento'
    },
    itens: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'  }]
});

var OrcamentoSchema = new Schema({
    contato: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Digite o nome do Contato',
        trim: true
    },
    curso: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Digite o Curso',
        trim: true
    },
    dias: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Digite os dias do curso',
        trim: true
    },
    inicio: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Digite a Data de Início'
    },
    detalhes: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Detalhe'}]
});

mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
mongoose.model('Detalhe', DetalheSchema);
mongoose.model('Orcamento', OrcamentoSchema);
```

my problem is that i can't get orcamento.detalhes[n].itens array to populate or even load, it just keeps showing as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Nested sub-document population is not supported.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/601

The only way to do it would be populate the 1st level sub-document and then loop over all the retrieved sub-documents and populate inside them. It is important to note here that internally this is the exact way that populate works in mongoose.

or you could use this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

Comment: Thanks. I will test mongoose-deep-populate.

Comment: can you accept answer once you are done testing it ?

Comment: When testing implementation mogoose-deep-populate, the following error occurred: warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 reconnect listener added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Comment: (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11        reconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListen
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:179:15)
    at Server.connect (F:\desenv\mean\joaomaria\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:291:17)
    at Db.open (F:\desenv\mean\joaomaria\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:196:19)